# Unity GUIText not visible and not WYSIWYG

Tags: c#, unity

I have placed a Guitext in my hierarchy:

[image]

At first it was visible, now I can't see it when I run the game.

When it was visible:

When modifying the position on scene, the GUIText appears on one place,
but when I run the game it's somewhere else.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you render your GUIText off-screen.

Position (x,y,z) of GUIText Object is relative to screen ration. It must be within 0..1 range. 0,0,0 means bottom left of the screen. 1,1,0 is top right.

Also, you have coordinates 0,0,0 (lower right) and anchor "upper left". This renders your GUIText just below the screen. What probably want to archive is: Position 0,0,0 and anchor "lower left"

But you shouldn't use the legacy GUI anymore. With Unity 4.6 the new uGUI System is available, more powerful and more performant.

The old GUI system is just slow, each GUI element causes a draw call and this kills performance on every mobile device. And it's very hard to work with, if the UI gets more complex than 2 buttons

Comment: where can I fond more info on uGUI?

Comment: This part of the Documentation is about the new GUI system (commonly called uGUI) http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIOverview.html.

Comment: thanks, by the way...do you have any experience on how to create a unity game for all mobile device resolutions? any hints?